# Apache Error.log showing attmepted access to other files in www root

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm seeing unauthenticated access attempts to files that don't exist in my web root.

```
[Sun Jul 26 13:00:03 2015] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /webrootpath/rom-0
[Sun Jul 26 14:06:04 2015] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /webrootpath/ic.asp
[Sun Jul 26 16:35:58 2015] [error] [client x.x.x.x] File does not exist: /webrootpath/phpmyadmin
```

I have apache running as non-root, non-admin and I have the following htaccess file (for codeigniter index.php re-write)

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

And here is my apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName domain.com
        ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /webrootpath/domain.com/html
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /webrootpath/domain.com/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I know very little about apache and .htaccess files, so I'm probably doing something really obviously stupid somewhere.

Comment: You know the origin of the client IPs ?

Comment: China and Poland so far 46.172.71.251,  182.91.244.219, 188.209.49.192. (they aren't people I'm expecting to hit the server)

Comment: They are probably bots checking out your server. I got that a lot since the first day my server was running publicly. Might as well check the auth log (if you're on linux), there are probably attempts to your ssh port too.

Comment: Correct. This doesn't seem like it should be normal though.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the norm. If you have MX record , you will see attempts for SMTP authentication and attempts to relay mail from your mail server too. You might want to try cloudflare

Comment: I loved the candid comment about normality :-)

Comment: I'll look into cloudflare